# OEM Install in XenServer guest

Tags: 12.04, virtualization

I am using a XenServer 6.2 pool with many Windows 2008/2012 servers as guests, which I have used SysPrep with to create templates to deploy new servers in minutes. Very cool. I now need to achieve this with Ubuntu.

I have created a VM and used Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS to do an "OEM Install" with the aim of booting the machine, adding some things like SSH server and custom APT repositories, then run "oem-prepare" (or whatever it is) and convert my VM into a template.

However, after installing the OS and waiting for the system to boot it is getting stuck with the stage "Stopping enable remaining boot-time encrypted block devices" - and goes no further.

Can anyone shed some light on this at all?

**UPDATE** This also happens in 12.04.4 too - so I have come to the conclusion that OEM Install is broken in Ubuntu Server